# SOL airdrop on devnet

Tags: devnet, airdrop

I have error since 3 days by trying to airdrop on devnet. the error message ist:

solana airdrop 1 AzCoTowEtJM4VZmUapoi56TkoD8GKieKJpg4WFsFMhJg --url

https://api.devnet.solana.com           
Requesting airdrop of 1 SOL
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem as you are.

Comment: I’m facing the same problem as you.

Answer (score 2):

People have been abusing the devent faucet and draining it. I think it may have just been refilled, but the faucet could continue to be unstable while efforts to mitigate people abusing it are in work.

Answer (score 1):

The faucet ran out of funds. now it works